# Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 doesn't show Windows Azure node in Server Explorer

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, server-explorer

Just installed VS Ultimate 2013 version 12.0.30110.00 Update 1, then went to the Windows Azure site and created an account. Also downloaded and installed the Windows Azure 2.2 SDK.

I open visual studio and go to Server Explorer. I see Data Connections, Servers (my machine), and SharePoint Connections.  I don't see a Windows Azure Node.  I look under the tools menu and see Connect to Database, Connect to Server, Add SharePoint connection.

So I download VS 2013 Express for Web, I open it and see under the tools menu Connect to Database, Connect to Windows Azure.  I open the server explorer and see Data Connections, Servers, Windows Azure.

Does the Azure functionality only exist in the Web Express version and not in the Ultimate 2013 version of Visual Studio?

Comment: Did you install [Azure SDK for .NET](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/visual-studio-2013/)?

Comment: Yes I did. version 2.2

Answer (score 2):

There is a separate set of tools for Windows Azure and Visual Studio. Depending on how you installed the SDK, you may not have received these tools: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee405484.aspx

Additionally, you may need to "sign in" via visual studio for it to see the items in your subscription. You should be able to do this by clicking on the "connect to windows azure" option in the server explorer.

Comment: There was no connect to Windows Azure in the server Explorer of VS 2013 Ultimate. That's the point. Only in VS 2013 Express for Web.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Azure node ships in the Azure SDK 2.2 and 2.3 as well as in all SKUs of Visual Studio 2013 Update 2. So you should be seeing the node if you have one of those installed.

Comment: When did Update 2 come out? After March 15th? And was it available in VS Ultimate 2013 in March or is this more recent? Kindly advise.

Comment: Correction.  Update 2 has not been officially released yet.  There is a release candidate available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42307).  The final release of Update 2 should be available shortly.

Comment: Regardless of Update 2, you should have the Azure node in server explorer with SDK 2.2.  In VS, check Help/About and see if "Common Azure Tools 1.x" is listed under installed products.  That component comes with the Azure SDK and provides the Azure node.  If you do not have it, I'd recommend removing 2.2 and try reinstalling.